# UIView to NSArray with key of cellForItemAtIndexPath and call on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionviewcell

For each of my cell created in the View Collection I need to have a `ProgressView` going. I'm working with a module where it's actually a view, so that's why I'm referring to the `UIView`.

I have everything working, except for the fact that once downloading it's only triggering the last instance of that specific Progress View.

I though I'd be able to resolve this by creating an `NSMutableArray`, inserting all instances of the `ProgressView` so it's saved.

Then once clicked on the button I can refer back to that exact specific Progress View inside that cell.

Unfortunately it's not adding them to the array. I've removed all the unnecessary code and just left the code I'm using:

In my `.h` file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSMutableArray *dldinges;
```

Then moving on the UICollectionViewCell

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     // cell.downloadProgressCircle comes from my UICollectionViewCell.h
    UIView *currentCell = cell.downloadProgressCircle;
    [dldinges insertObject:currentCell atIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"Cell: %@",currentCell);
    NSLog(@"Collection: %@",dldinges);

}
```

Then at the button click:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender { 

CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.IssuesOverviewCollection]; 

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.IssuesOverviewCollection indexPathForItemAtPoint:buttonPosition];

UIView *progressButton = [[UIView alloc]init];
progressButton = [dldinges objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
progressButton.percentage = 0.5;
```

}

Comment: Would love to help, here, but I've read and re-read and I can't make heads or tails of the question.  Could you try to restate: what do you want to happen, what's happening instead, show the code that's not doing what you want it to do.  Please use whole methods not fragments.

Comment: @danh I'm loading the cell of collectionview dynamic from a json, inside each view collection cell there's an UIView, which on the click of a button (which is inside the Cell) has to do something, but ONLY the specific UI View inside that cell, not to all. So the button click inside the specific cell should ONLY influence the UIView from that same cell. I've added a bit more code to the button part what's happening now.

Comment: *"it's not adding them to the array"* - what happens instead? How do you know they're not being added to the array?

Comment: @CarlVeazey the nslog is not displaying it. It does display the "currentCell"

Comment: What does the log print instead?

Comment: @CarlVeazey The Collection Array prints: (null).  The "CurrentCell" which needs to be in the Collection Array prints: "<UIView: 0xe252b60; frame = (113 274; 30 30); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xe252c30>>" (this last one is different for each cell)

Comment: So where did you instantiate the mutable array?

Comment: So what @CarlVeazey is trying to communicate is that this question could just as easily be restated as, "I can't add objects to a mutable array".  We probably shouldn't interactively debug here in chat.  Not to mention, after we get the array working, we're totally not going to want an array of progress UIViews, but rather an array of NSNumbers representing progress.  I think you're going to need to break this down to simpler questions, starting with the array add.

Comment: @CarlVeazey thanks! Completely forgot about instantiating the nsmutablearray.

Comment: @GeertSamuel you're welcome... with your next question, please include the information from the start rather than make people play 20 questions :)